# How to print data for a specific value (string) from a data frame (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that contains fertility rates for different countries and I'd like to: 
1. rename columns 
2. Print out only specific countries (not using index but names)

Here I import data from website

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2127.html')
```

Then I try to rename columns (from '0' to 'Country' and from '1' to 'TFR'):

```
df= df.rename(index=str, columns ={'0':'Country', '1':'TFR'})
```

But I get error message:

```
df = df.rename(index=str, columns ={'0':'Country', '1':'TFR'})
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

This is the way in which I try to look for specific country:

```
print(df[df['0'].str.contains("Tanzan")])
```

And I get following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong? How to sort it out (if it is possible)? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't read the HTML - I get an encoding error. But for the columns just do `fertilityRateByCountry.columns = ['Country', 'TFR']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add parameter `header=0` for convert first row of page to header of DataFrame and then add `[0]` for select first DataFrame from list of DataFrames:

```
url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2127.html'
d = {'TOTAL FERTILITY RATE(CHILDREN BORN/WOMAN)':'TFR'}
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0].rename(columns=d)
print (df.head())
          Country                                   TFR
0     Afghanistan  5.12 children born/woman (2017 est.)
1         Albania  1.51 children born/woman (2017 est.)
2         Algeria   2.7 children born/woman (2017 est.)
3  American Samoa  2.68 children born/woman (2017 est.)
4         Andorra   1.4 children born/woman (2017 est.)
```

Last filter by new column name:

```
print(df[df['Country'].str.contains("Tanzan")])
      Country                                   TFR
204  Tanzania  4.77 children born/woman (2017 est.)
```

Comment: This is awesome , `df  = pd.read_html(input('Please Enter the urlname: '), header=0, flavor='bs4')[0]`

Comment: @pygo - then rather `df = pd.read_html(input('Please Enter the urlname: '), header=0, flavor='bs4')[0]`, because select first DataFrame form list ;)

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you for help. I have came across another issue and thought that you might know what to do: how to access TFR column values so I can remove 'children born/woman (2017 est.)'?

Comment: @ugabuga77 - You can use `df['TFR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TFR'].str[:-31])`, because there is also one value `'children born/woman (2015 est.)`

Comment: @jezrael: I managed to do it in a different way but yours is more elegant and efficient. Thank you very much.